# Is it possible to show a 404 page for not found routes in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Am using nestjs to handle all the apis. I want to show a 404 page if a route is not found.

Answer (score 9):

The right solution is to use `ExceptionFilter` as pointed out by @eol but to allow dependency injection you should register them on a module, instead of using `useGlobalFilters` ([as pointed out in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#binding-filters)):

```
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(_exception: NotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    response.sendFile('./path/to/your/404-page.html');
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: NotFoundExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will also register them globally.

Comment: There is a greatest answer with clear pure solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can define a custom global [`ExceptionFilter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1) that catches a `NotFoundException` exception and then handle the error accordingly:

```
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: NotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse();
        response.sendFile('./path/to/your/404-page.html');
    }
}
```

You can set this exception filter as `global` as follows:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);    
  // ...
  app.useGlobalFilters(new NotFoundExceptionFilter());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Do I have to bind this every controller?

Comment: No, you can define it as a global exepction handler. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: When I use this, all the validation pipes are failing.

Comment: I've added an argument to the `Catch()`-decorator to only catch `NotFoundException` errors. Can you try again?

Comment: Maybe you want to set the http status code to `NotFound`. The you need to add `response.status(404)` before `response.sendFile`

Comment: How does one differentiate between the NotFoundException for a route not found and the one for custom reasons?

Comment: seems response.sendFile is not working for the fastify
 and even `const file = fs.createReadStream(
      path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/prerendered/index.html'),
    ); response.type('text/html').send(file);`